# Multiple jQuery UI Date Range Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There is a way to add more than one `jQuery Date pickers` but i am trying very hard to achieve Multiple `jQuery Date Range Picker` on a single page.
This is what i have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/ZJRHx/1/

```
<div class="demo">
    <div class="settings">
        <label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="pdate"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" class="fdate"/>
    </div>
    <div class="settings">
        <label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" name="from" class="pdate"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" name="to" class="fdate"/>
    </div>
</div>



$('.demo').find('.settings').each(function() {
        var dates = $(this).find( ".pdate, .fdate" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = $(this).class == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );

                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
```

But i canot solve the Range Part Yet.

Comment: Your fiddle complains of multiple access denied requests and not having datepicker as a function, you may want to check the urls you're fetching with.

Comment: It seems to be working for me (although missing some CSS), unless I misunderstand your question. I did need to tick the jquery UI checkbox on jsfiddle first though. What isn't working for you?

Comment: Range prblm still dere !!  alerting option is always maxDate

Answer (score 1):

You are including jquery ui from jqueryui.com, that isn't allowed and will result in the files not loading properly. Here is a fiddle with your code mostly working: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJRHx/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did:
First you nest your inputs to receive the date ranges:

```
<div class="date_range">
     <input class="date_min calendar" name="min" />
    <input class="date_max calendar" name="max" /></div>
```

Then you create this script:

```
var dates = $( ".date_min, .date_max" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear:true,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = $(this).hasClass("date_min") ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            brother = $(this).hasClass("date_min") ? ".date_max" : ".date_min",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||  $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.closest(brother).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        },
        beforeShow:function(){
            var brother =$(this).hasClass("date_min") ? ".date_max" : ".date_min",
            option = $(this).hasClass("date_max") ? "minDate" : "maxDate";
            if($(this).siblings(brother).val() == ""){
               dates.datepicker("refresh").datepicker("option", option, null);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am using this code to send dates to filter different graph and it works like a charm.